# Filter prefetched data while using twitter typeahead plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead

I have two input fields on my page: country and city. 
First one contains 100 choices and second - 2000 choices. I want to use prefetch option in [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) plugin, because these input fields are being reused on other pages.

Then I want to filter prefetched data while typing in city input. How can I do that?

Simple answer is to use [remote](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#remote) option of typeahead, populate url with 'country' parameter and filter data on server side. Works great but I want to use prefetch data stored on client.

Second answer is to listen to 'typeahead:selected' event and show alert message if city doesn't correspond to country. It is bad solution.

So how can I filter prefetched data?

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found in [this](https://github.com/livechat/typeahead.js/commit/6bb7990a5a1f514e6a030a6d52e91477bd3fc8a4) commit. Just use `suggestionsCallback` function to filter your suggests.